# Can't understand shorthand code in palindrome

Tags: c++, palindrome

I can't understand this code, please explain to me what is happening in the second line of the for loop.

```
#include <cstdio>
char s[5005000];
int h[5005000];
const int M=3;
int main() {
  scanf("%s",s);
  int a=0,b=0,p=1,v=0;
  for(int i=0;s[i];++i){
    a=a*M+s[i],b+=s[i]*p,p*=M;
    if(a==b)v+=(h[i+1]=h[(i+1)>>1]+1);
  }
  printf("%d\n",v);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Debug printf's or walking single-step with any reasonable debugger would likely say  as much as any answer here. Have you tried either?

Comment: It would probably also help if you replaced those single-letter variable names with more descriptive names as you decipher the algorithm. `s`, for example, could be renamed to `input_string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It checks if the string in [0, i] interval is palindrome or not by using ASCII
for example if the string is **a2a**
---------------------------
**i = 0**
---------------------------
a = a * M + str[0] = 97
b += str[0] * p = 97
p * = M -> p = 3
Since a == b then h[1] = h[1>>1] + 1 = 1 and v += h[1], therefore v = 1
---------------------------
**i = 1**
---------------------------
a = a * M + str[1] = 97*3 + 50 = 341
b += str[1] * p = 97 + 50*3 = 247
p * = M -> p = 9
Since a != b then nothing happens

---------------------------
**i = 2**
---------------------------
a = a * M + str[2] = 341*3 + 97 = 1120
b += str[2]*p = 247 + 97*9 = 1120
p *= M -> p = 27
Since a == b then h[3] = h[3>>1] + 1 = 2 and v += h[3], therefore v = 3
---------------------------

Finally, v = 3

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

```
a=a*M+s[i],b+=s[i]*p,p*=M;
```

is using the "comma operator". The comma operator evaluates the left side, throws the result away, then evaluates the right side and returns the result.

In this code it has the exact same effect as a semicolon. Apparently the author of this code thinks that there is some reason to prefer the comma operator here instead of using semicolons -- I don't agree but that's just my opinion.